# How to Pass variable between Different View Controller in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i try this code but it didn't work for me.
Thank You

```
-(void)passvar:(NSString *)user
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signupvc"];

viewController.user = user;

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewController` does not have an `user` property.
You should use your custom subclass instead of `UIVIewController`

```
-(void)passvar:(NSString *)user
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MyCustomViewController *viewController = (MyCustomViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signupvc"];

viewController.user = user;

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Note that in this code, you instantiate a **new** `MyCustomViewController` from the storyboard and present it to the user. It has nothing to do with any other View Controller that you opened before calling those line of code.
If you call this function 3 times, it will open 3 different `MyCustomViewController`.